# How to sign apk with google app signing upload key

Tags: android, apk, android-app-signing

I lost my pepk.jar file but I do have keystore which I generated when I did first time sign apk and published in google console. I tried to sign updated apk and upload in console but it says

You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
[SHA1--------------------------]

and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:
[SHA1------------------------------]

I tried this way

```
keytool.exe -importcert -file upload_cert.der -keystore <keystorefile>
```

but then after I sign the apk with new keystore as generated from above, it throws the same error.

I checked my SHA1 for both new and old apk as follows

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile original.apk
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile update.apk
```

I got the different SHA1 but now the problem is how to use the original SHA1 to sign the new apk?

Can anyone guide me how to overcome this problem?

I do not want to create new package and sign the new app as users are big in size who have downloaded this app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have enrolled in App Signing by Google Play. When you enrolled, you have created another keystore (or possibly created a new key in an existing keystore) and generated a new certificate that you uploaded to the Play Console. You must find and use that keystore and the associated alias/password to sign your APKs.

If you have lost it, you can reset your upload key by contacting the Google Play support team. See "Create a new upload key" on [this page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yea it seems like I had created another keystore and generated a new cert and uploaded to Play Console. Unfortunately, I can not find that because developer took the laptop and I contacted to google support team. Hopefully they will provide soon.